# Pass each from File as as an argument to different Array in shell

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I want to pass each either row or column of the file as an argument to a different array.

```
The file name is Entry.txt

Pool Library Name
Backup lib1  Deepak
Clone  lib2  Raju
Tape   lib3  Guru

Code is :

read -r -a array < Entry.txt

pool=("${array[0]}")
library=("${array[1]}")
Name=("${array[2]}")
```

Now, the problem is that I am getting input in the pool array only but not getting any values in other arrays.

My need is having array like:

```
pool=(Backup Clone Tape)
Library=(lib1 lib2 lib3)
Name=(Deepak Raju Guru)
```

Please help.

Comment: Is your file separated by tabs or spaces?

Comment: 1. Remove first line. 2. Transpose the file (you can find awk script to that on stackoverflow) 3. Read the file line by line into an array.

Comment: its separated by space

Comment: @KamilCuk Please help me with code. I am beginner in Scripting Sir

Answer (score 1):

`read -a` (without a custom `-d`) reads the words in one line. However, you want to read the entries, that is, lines from a column, therefore use `mapfile`. To read each column into its own array

- Extract each column
- Remove the header
- Read each column (without header) into an array

The first two points can be done in one `awk` one-liner.

```
mapfile -t pool    < <(awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' yourFile)
mapfile -t library < <(awk 'NR > 1 {print $2}' yourFile)
mapfile -t name    < <(awk 'NR > 1 {print $3}' yourFile)
```

Or in a loop

```
column=1
for arrayname in pool library name; do
     mapfile -t "$arrayname" < <(awk "NR > 1 {print \$$column}" yourFile)
     ((column++))
done
```

You can [test this solution online](https://repl.it/repls/BustlingEnlightenedApplicationprogrammer).

Comment: I am not bothered about the header and also can modify the file from row to column or vice versa. I am just bothered about to pass the arguments to array from file. Please help me getting complete code for it

Comment: I don't understand. In your question you wrote `My need is having array like: ...` and this solution produces these arrays. What exactly are you missing? What are "*the arguments*"?

Comment: No its not producing correct output.For echo "${pool[@]}"                                 output is only Tape. whereas I want it to have   "Backup Clone Tape"

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. For me, everything works. Could it be, that your file has windows line endings? Please run `declare -p pool` instead of `echo "${pool[@]}"` and show us the output.

Comment: No its simple text file. but i not ghetting the desired result

Comment: Windows line endings are simple text too, but you cannot see them. Please run `declare -p pool` and show us the output.

Comment: declare -a pool='([0]="Tape" [1]="")'

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem. I tested both solutions multiple times with your example input on my system and in an online service ([test it yourself](https://repl.it/repls/BustlingEnlightenedApplicationprogrammer)). Your file must be different from the one you showed us or your system differs from the standard (did you overwrite some commands?). Some pointers for debugging: Show the output of `ps $$` (to confirm that you are using `bash`). Show the output of `hexdump -c yourFile` (to confirm that your file is correct). Show the output of `bash --version`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202980/discussion-between-guru-singh-and-socowi).

Comment: @Socowi- Bro your solution works great but there is one small issue i am facing like if any Name consists of two words separated by space then also its not able to recognize it.. like

Comment: [root@Server MM]# cat file.txt
    Pool    Library Name
    Backup  Lib1    Guru Singh
    clone   Lib2    Raju
    Tape    Lib3    Deepak
    [root@Server MM]# column=1
    [root@Server MM]# for arrayname in Pool Library Name; do      mapfile -t "$arrayname" < <(awk "NR > 1 {print \$$column}" file.txt);      ((column++)); done;
    [root@Server MM]# echo ${Name[@]}
    Guru Raju Deepak
    [root@Server MM]#
    I want it to be as 
    [root@Server MM]# echo ${Name[@]}
    Guru Singh Deepak Raju
    [root@Server MM]#

Comment: @socowi..Help please

Comment: In general such a file cannot be parsed. You have to delimit by tabs if you want to use spaces as data. However, here the field with spaces is the last one in the row, so you could (in the non-loop version) replace that last line with `mapfile -t name < <(awk 'NR > 1 && sub(/^([^ ]+ +){2}/,"")' yourFile)`.